# Submit with a button who launches Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit, bootstrap-modal

I have a form that i submit with a input type button.

```
<input class="btn btn-info pull-right" type="submit" value="Post"/><br />
```

Now id, like to change the submit of my form to a button who also loads the data in a Bootstrap Modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Post</button>
```

How do i combine those two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" value="Post" />
```

Comment: Thank you! The form posts and the Modal is triggered. The strange part is that the modal only "flashes" by. open/close. What can cause this?

Comment: @Mjukis: I think you should use ajax submit and call the modal from javascript !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Post" readonly="readonly" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

Adding readonly tag would be beneficial.Also no need of Red button for submit ,you can use primary button (green colored).